# Bootstrap 3 Navbar toggle - collapses but button does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but I expect it's something woefully stupid.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 in Umbraco 6.0.5 and I cannot get the toggle to work on resize down - below 770px width the nav collapses but there's no button to toggle it with, or rather something is there, as seen in code and Firebug, but not visible, in Chrome and Firefox (haven't tried IE).

There's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2eCY/) and the code below. I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js, http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js and http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css in the fiddle.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href"#">reech</a>  
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/" class="selected">Home</a></li>
        <li class=" dropdown">
          <a href="/what-is-reech.aspx" class=" dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" rel="">What is reech? <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/what-is-reech/about-this-site.aspx" rel="">About this site</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" dropdown">
        </li>
        <li><a href="/key-reech-projects.aspx" class="" rel="">Key reech projects</a></li> 
        <li class=" dropdown">
        </li>
        <li><a href="/technologies.aspx" class="" rel="">Technologies</a></li> 
        <li class=" dropdown">
        </li>
        <li><a href="/complementary-activities.aspx" class="" rel="">Complementary Activities</a></li> 
        <li class=" dropdown">
          <a href="/news.aspx" class=" dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" rel="">News <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/news/merseyside-collective-switching-scheme-launched.aspx" rel="">Merseyside collective switching scheme launched</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/reech-scoops-top-award.aspx" rel="">reech scoops top award</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/reech-award-nomination.aspx" rel="">reech award nomination</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/green-deal-and-energy-company-obligation-(eco)-september-2013-statistics.aspx" rel="">Green Deal and Energy Company Obligation (ECO) September 2013 Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/energy-switching-scheme.aspx" rel="">Energy Switching Scheme</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/project-reeches-new-milestone.aspx" rel="">Project &#39;reeches&#39; new milestone</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/firms-sign-up-for-new-opportunities.aspx" rel="">Firms sign up for new opportunities</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/14-new-jobs-created-for-merseyside-residents.aspx" rel="">14 new jobs created for Merseyside residents</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news/reeching-out-to-low-carbon-and-green-energy-sector.aspx" rel="">&#39;reeching&#39; out to Low Carbon and Green Energy Sector</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" dropdown">
        </li>
        <li><a href="/reech-into-business.aspx" class="" rel="">reech into business</a></li> 
        <li class=" dropdown">
          <a href="/reech-partners.aspx" class=" dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" rel="">reech partners <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/reech-partners/reech-steering-group.aspx" rel="">reech Steering Group</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div><!--close navbar-collapse-->
  </div><!--close container-->
</nav><!--Close nav-->
```

Update - so, I tried altering the data-target (and have altered the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kelpie/D2eCY/16/)) to #main-nav and the id to main-nav, no joy.
The I tried putting a dash character in the button > span element, and it works. That is, the dashes display, and I can toggle the menu. But where are the icon bars?

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar">-</span>
    <span class="icon-bar">-</span>
    <span class="icon-bar">-</span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

And change `<nav class="navbar">` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

Comment: You were right! I was trying to get clever with it and broke it. That'll teach me!

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap - the toggle button will not show in mobile view

FIX:
Make these changes at: bootstrap.min.css

## This fixes the outer border of the Toggle Button

```
.navbar-toggle
{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    padding:9px 10px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:none;
    border-radius:4px
}
```

Add

```
border:1px solid #444;
```

(change color code to match your design)

```
.navbar-toggle
{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    padding:9px 10px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:none;
    border:1px solid #444;          /* added line */
    border-radius:4px
}
```

## This fixes the horizontal lines of the Toggle Button

```
.icon-bar
{
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:2px;
    border-radius:1px;
}
```

Add

```
border:1px solid #444;
```

(change color code to match your design)

```
.icon-bar
{
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:2px;
    border-radius:1px;
    border:1px solid #444;
}
```

Comment: Just add **.navbar-default** class instead of writing a long code!

Answer (score 4):

In your 1st line

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

it should be `data-target="#nav-collapse"` because you have `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">` where id is `nav-collapse`

Answer (score 3):

This should get you pointed in the correct direction.  It looks like your main hiccup is your button data-target attribute is referencing a class rather than an ID.  It's best to use an ID in this situation so if you call that class elsewhere in the code your not throwing curve balls at the javascript.

I also see you have several `<li class="dropdown"></li>` that are blank.  I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, but I would refer to the structure that I've enclosed.

Hope this works for you, and best of luck!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Reech</a> </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/what-is-reech.apsx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">What is reech? <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/what-is-reech/about-this-site-aspx">About this site</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li><!-- dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/what-is-reech.apsx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Key reech projects <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/technologies.apsx">Technologies</a></li>
            <li><a href="/complementary-activities.apsx">Complementary Activities</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li><!-- dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/what-is-reech.apsx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Key reech projects <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/technologies.apsx">Technologies</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li><!-- dropdown -->
      </ul><!-- nav navbar-nav -->
    </div><!-- collapse navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
```